# CSS Background Gradient Position not Animating

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a website where I want a linear-gradient to scroll indefinitely to the left. I have it working perfectly right here on codepen: http://codepen.io/spikeyty/pen/oqBFi

It appears that the gradient is there, but it is not moving. I copied the code straight from codepen. Here is the website I'm adjusting: http://tystrong.me

It isn't working in Chrome, Firefox, or Internet Explorer. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query on line 99 (code pen) is wrapping the declaration of the `bg-move` animation property so it does not exist at the desktop view.

Also - bit of a  protip, you don't need to specify `from` in your animation declaration when it is the default state of the element already.

BTW - sweet little effect!

Comment: This is **AWESOME**. Thank you so much for catching that!